# React Meta Tags Server Side

Tags: reactjs, meta-tags

I have completed the meta tags implementation in react js at client side using react document meta and my title has changed.However I am confused about the server side prerendering for meta tags.I am completely new at this.I have gone through links like [React-document-data](https://github.com/kodyl/react-document-meta) and Npm [React-document-meta](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-document-meta) but could not get through server side rendering.Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've been doing this recently with expressjs and I think I've cracked it!

Firstly you're going to want to make one singular instance of your react 'app' which will be babel-ified. I tend to stick everything in an src and babel it to dist. My main for the server then ends up being `/dist/index.js` and this includes my app using `dist/App/index.js.

Next you're going to want to make your assets because rendering locally within a node process is very different to on a DOM.

Ok so firstly `src/index.js`

```
import express from 'express';
import app from './App';
import Mailgun from 'mailgun-js';

const server = express();

server.use(express.static('public'));

const port = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 3000;

server.get('/*', function(request, response) {
    response.send(app());
});
```

This is my `App/index.js` file which is my initial content not my react app!

```
import * as assets from './../Assets';
import App from './app';
import React from 'react';
import {renderToString} from 'react-dom/server';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import createStore from './Store';

import reducers from './Reducers';
import sagas from './Sagas';

//const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();
const store = createStore({}, reducers, sagas);

const html = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
);

export default function render () {
    return `<!doctype html>
    <html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
      <head lang="en">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Preloaded title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/${assets.get('index.css')}"/>
        <div id="root">${html}</div>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          // WARNING: See the following for security issues around embedding JSON in HTML:
          // http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html#security-considerations
          window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(store.getState()).replace(/</g, '\\u003c')}
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="build/${assets.get('index.js')}"></script>
      </body>
    </html>`;
}
```

the `assets.get()` function is essentially returning a full url to my assets based on a manifest file. Ignore this for now. Not particularly important.

That's essentially it for pre-rendering. Now you'll need a different version for the build js for rehydrating your react app.

So `assets/js/index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import createStore from './../../src/App/Store';
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';

import reducers from './../../src/App/Reducers';
import sagas from './../../src/App/Sagas';

import App from './../../src/App/app';

const preloadedState = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__;

// Allow the passed state to be garbage-collected
delete window.__PRELOADED_STATE__;

preloadedState.server.env = false;

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();
const store = createStore(browserHistory, reducers, sagas, preloadedState);


ReactDOM.hydrate(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

notice `ReactDOM.hydrate` not `ReactDOM.render`.

In this file you can add your google analytic etc. Anything to do with the DOM/window, DOM load etc.

And that's essentially it! I used the below example to work from.

https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer...two questions though 1)if i want to add description and keywords it will be in head tag where title and viewport are there? 2)will this work with react document meta on client side...i mean i saw terms like DocumentMeta.rewind() to be used on server side...so was not sure

Comment: erm personally not used react documentMeta but I've used react-helmet within my app itself which is rendered. You can effectively do both! but bear in mind anything in that string will be overwritten. You're probably good to use it. Probably does the same thing

Comment: Thanks !!will just try that out

Comment: pastbin, repo or anything you want me to take a look at?

Comment: Hey..its done...only things my metatags change as per url...how to get current url in node.js?

Comment: that's a good question!! I'm using PM2 and the PM2 docker so I used ENV vars to change my environments from dev and live and had a hardcoded url for the server and `window.location` for client side

Comment: no....my metatags change per page...not by environment...so i need need the current url to know the page on the server side

Comment: I am using cpanel/whm linux setup it always gives error like port 80 not accessible or if i chnage port to 3000 for apache it gives error port already in use for listing that port